# O uso da raiz quadrada em edgeR via Rstudio

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber se alguém já tentou usar `sqrt` no `edgeR` via `Rstudio` para aumentar seu N e significância. Eu estava tendo   alguns problemas com os meus reads (`RefSeq`) como Ns baixo e baixo número de expressão diferencial, então, eu tentei aplicar sqrt em meus reads para aproximar meus valores.

Eu preciso saber duas coisas: **1)** Isso é viável matematicamente? **2)** Alguém já tentou?